# PHP print "even" or "odd" without using control structures

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php, logic

How to check in PHP or JavaScript to display a given digit is EVEN or ODD **without** using conditional operators or control structures (i.e. without if, for, foreach, do-while, etc)?

For example, If my input is 20 then system should output "EVEN" and for the input 21 output should be "ODD" . Likewise for any numbers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Something like this in C? `puts("EVEN\0ODD" + 5 * (some condition));`

Comment: Would you mind defining the input and output more specificly? What is "a given input digit"?

Comment: Compute the remainder of the number divided by two. That will be either zero or one. Use that value to index into an array containing the words "even" and "odd".

Comment: So you need to write "EVEN" or "ODD" in the output based on some input?

Comment: yes, Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: But I dont know why this got negetive points !!!! I am not much experienced with  stackoverflow. Any mistake I did?

Comment: Perhaps because your question was too broad, ie. "*Is there a way in [6] different languages to display...*" Just a thought. And having no code to work with could be a reason, too. I up'd you 'cause it was an interesting question. Seems to fit within the *rules*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP

```
$vals = ['EVEN','ODD'];
echo $vals[$digit % 2];
```

Answer (score 4):

In javascript, using [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) `&`

```
var n = 3;
['EVEN', 'ODD'][n & 1]; // ODD

var n = 4;
['EVEN', 'ODD'][n & 1]; // EVEN
```

Snippet:

```js
document.write(['EVEN', 'ODD'][3 & 1]);
document.write('<br>')
document.write(['EVEN', 'ODD'][4 & 1]);
```

Comment: @Tomasito665 it converts to `true` or `false`

Comment: I believe OP is asking for an output of EVEN || ODD, not true/false. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Marcus made with EVEN || ODD

Answer (score 3):

C# How about

```
var x = new []{"EVEN", "ODD"}[(i & 1)];
```

Comment: Other language answers can be written in the same spirit. In fact I think Java would work with this syntax if you are more explicit on data type.

Comment: Yea, i & 1 is a 1/0 toggle so there are lots of ways.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in C# it would look like this:

```
var evenodd = new[] { "even", "odd" };

var digit = 1; // or however you get your digit

Console.WriteLine(evenodd[digit % 2]);
```

Pretty simple - by doing `% 2` on the value you get either a 1 or 0 back, which you can then use as an index into the array. You would be able to use this method in any of the languages you list.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it counts, but Java could do `System.out.println(input % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");` ... It is a hidden `if()` though

Comment: It's called a ternary operator.

Comment: I think in the spirit of the question, `? :` would count as a "control structure".

Comment: Yeah, the ternary operator is in essence an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based off @[Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36625121/3126629)'s nifty little (PHP) code:

```
$eo = function($d, $a = ['EVEN','ODD']) {
    return $a[$d % 2];
};
echo $eo($digit);
```